# Android JUnit5 Dependency for the Whole Project

Tags: android, gradle, junit

PROBLEM Attaching JUint5 to an instant app project in Android Studio.

RESEARCH Works fine when added to each feature's gradle file:

```
`dependencies {
  ...

  testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter',
              name: 'junit-jupiter-api',
              version: '5.0.0-M1'
  testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.9.6'
}`
```

QUESTION Can I add these dependencies once for the whole project (Project Gradle or App Gradle and InstantApp Gradle)?

Project gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And base gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 26
  baseFeature true
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
        'proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
  defaultConfig {
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
  compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility 1.8
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
  }
}

dependencies {
  api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
  api 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
  implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

  application project(
    ':app')
  feature project(
    ':feature_navigate')

  testCompile 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.0'
  testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.13.1'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

  testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.13.0'

  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.1'
  androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
  androidTestCompile  'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.3'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a multi-project Gradle build issue [doc reference](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html).

Assume, you have the project setup within in the `settings.gradle`:

```
include "x", "y"
rootProject.name = 'root-folder'
```

Project layout as this:

```
|- root-folder
|- build.gradle
|- setting.gradle
|-- x
|-- y
```

Then you can add the below lines to your `root-folder.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
  dependencies {
  ...

  testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter',
              name: 'junit-jupiter-api',
              version: '5.0.0-M1'
  testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.9.6'
  }
}
```

It would be applied to all projects.

Comment: Moving test dependencies from "base" module gradle file to "allprojects dependecies" in project gradle file result in an error: "Could not find method api() for arguments [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler." Tests won't start.

Comment: @Zon, you need to have your android set of dependencies in allprojects scope as well, the error tells you that there is Android plugin missing.

Comment: @Zon can you paste your `build.gradle`

Comment: Updated in question.